# Converting a List Into Float Variables

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, floating-point

I'm wanting to take an input as a list but use each variable as a float. Is there a simpler way to make this conversion other than explicitly like I do below, as a list is defined with strings, and I want to, for example, add rather than concatenate:

```
edges = input("Enter three edges: ").split(", ")  
print("The perimeter is", (float(edges[0]) + float(edges[1]) + float(edges[2])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` to transform to `float`s and then `sum` to sum them up:

```
print("The perimeter is", sum(map(float, edges)))
```

`map` takes a callable (`float` here), and applies it to every element of an iterable (`edges` here). This creates a `map` iterator (something that can be iterated through) that is then supplied to `sum` which sums it up.

Then you print it.

You could of course create an ugly little expression that combines them all together because both `input` and `split` return their results:

```
print("Sum is ", sum(map(float, input('Enter three edges ' ).split(","))))
```

but don't, *it's ugly*.

Answer (score 1):

map is your friend

```
sum(map(float, edges))
```

or a generator expression

```
sum(float(f) for f in edges)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably want the edges only as numbers, you can convert them early:

```
edges = [float(edge) for edge in input("Enter three edges: ").split(", ")]
print("The perimeter is", sum(edges))
```

Sample run:

```
Enter three edges: 1.2, 3.4, 5.6
The perimeter is 10.2
```